# Central limit theorem ... need help

Tags: probability, probability-theory, central-limit-theorem

So far I have used Chebychev's inequality to calculate $n = 157$, and my initial thinking for applying the central limit theorem is $-1.2815 = (5-0n)/(n^\sqrt{391/n}) $because $P(Z > -1.2815) = 90%$, however this isn't giving me the correct value for $n$ so I'm not sure what to try now.

"You want to determine the melting point
$c$
of a new material. You have
$n$
specimens on each of which you make a measurement of the melting point in degrees Kelvin, giving you a dataset
$m_1,…,m_n$.  We model this with random variables
$M_i=c+U_i$, where
$U_i$
is the random measurement error. It is known that
$E[U_i]=0$
and $Var(U_i)=391$ for each $i$, and that we may consider the random variables $M_1,M_2,…$
as independent.

how many measurements do you need to perform to be
90%
sure that the average of the measurements is within
5
degrees of
c?

Use the normal approximation (central limit theorem rule of thumb) to find a value for
n
. You can use that the
0.95
quantile of the standard normal distribution is
q(0.95)≈1.645
."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

\begin{align}
P \left(\left| \frac{\sum_{i=1}^nM_i}{n}-c\right|<5 \right)&=P \left(\sqrt{n}\left| \frac{\sum_{i=1}^nM_i}{n}-c\right|<5\sqrt{n} \right)\\
&\approx P\left(|Z|<\frac{5\sqrt{n}}{\sqrt{Var(U_i)}}\right)
\end{align}

That is we want $$\frac{5\sqrt{n}}{\sqrt{Var(U_i)}}\ge 1.645$$